# Relation in relational model : heading and body meaning?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

A relation in the relational model is what SQL represents with a table. We could say that a table is an attempt by SQL to represent a relation.
Getting back to a relation, which is what SQL attempts to represent with a table: a relation
has a heading and a body. The heading is a set of attributes (what SQL attempts to represent
with columns), each of a given type. An attribute is identified by name and type name. The
body is a set of tuples (what SQL attempts to represent with rows). Each tuple’s heading is the
heading of the relation. Each value of each tuple’s attribute is of its respective type.

What do we mean by the heading of a relation is a set of attributes, and the body is a set of tuples?

If we consider these two tables :

```
Employee : EmployeeId,FirstName,LastName,DepartmentId

Department : DepartmentId, DepartmentName, Description
```

If I want to select the employees and their departments, the query will be like following :

```
SELECT * FROM Employee E
LEFT Department D ON E.DepartmentId=D.DepartmentId
```

In this case what is the heading and the body corresponding to mathematic definition of relational ?

Comment: This is a resultset, not a relation (though it can be treated as one, providing all the column names are unique - which is not true in this case - you have `DepartmentId` twice).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### In the relational model

An **attribute** is a name paired with a data type.

A set of **attributes** with unique names is called a **heading**.

A **tuple** is a set of **attribute values** corresponding to a specific **heading**.

A **relation** is a unsorted, unique set of **tuples**.

A **tuple** can only be a part of a **relation** if their **heading** match exactly.

A set of **tuples** that all correspond to the same **heading** is called a **body**.

Therefor, a **relation** the combination of a specific **heading** and a **body** (which is a set of **tuples** that correspond to this **heading**).

### In a relational database

A **relation** is implemented as a table.
(Note: The relational model describes the tuples in a relation as unique, but no RDBMS I know of enforces that rule unless a unique key (in the form of a primary key, unique constraint or unique index) is declared.

A **Heading** is the table's column definition.

A **tuple** is a row within a table.

An **attribute value** is the value of a specific column in a specific row.

### To answer your question

> In this case what is the heading and the body corresponding to mathematic definition of relational ?

Given the tables you've described in your question, and the query you're using to select from these table, the resultset of that query can not be considered as a relation, since it has a duplicate attribute in it's heading - the `DepartmentId` column exists in both source tables.

This is why the database will not let you create a view (or a cte) from this query - since a view or cte column names must be unique in order to provide a proper heading.

For more information, read [Relation (database)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relation_(database)) over on Wikipedia.